# Set underlying data in class extends Array

Tags: javascript

In python, I can extend the list type and have direct access to the underlying data (by using the class' data variable), resetting it completely if I want to:

```py
import collections

class myList(collections.UserList):

  def sort(self):
    self.data = sorted(self.data, key=operator.itemgetter('mySortKey'))
```

How do I achieve this in javascript?

```js
class myList extends Array {

  sort(){
    this = this.slice().sort( compareFunc_mySortKey ); // This doesn't appear to work
  }

}
```

Comment: Are you wanting to replace native array sort method?

Comment: `this` is read-only. Try `sort() { return super.sort(compareFunc_mySortKey); }`

Comment: @charlietfl - not necessarily, sort was just an example. Sorry for the confusion.